# Coloured progress lines - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have one requirement where I need to show multiple progress lines can be n number of lines.

current line should be in gradient colour where previous lines should be in green and next lines should be in grey.

[image: Image for reference]

I am expecting a view similar to the image added and everything should be done from storyboard I don't want to take any outlets on my view controller class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi You can use the below mentioned code for achieving the result :

```
@IBDesignable
class PageProgressView: UIView {
    
    @IBInspectable var statusLines: Int = 1 {
        didSet {
            setupStatusLines()
        }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable var currentLineIndex: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            setupStatusLines()
        }
    }
    
    
    @IBInspectable var previousColor: UIColor = UIColor(red: 0.44, green: 0.81, blue: 0.59, alpha: 1) {
        didSet {
            setupStatusLines()
        }
    }
    
    
    @IBInspectable var nextColor: UIColor = UIColor(red: 0.22, green: 0.22, blue: 0.31, alpha: 1) {
        didSet {
            setupStatusLines()
        }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable var gradientStart: UIColor = UIColor(resource: .secondary) {
        didSet {
            setupStatusLines()
        }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable var gradientEnd: UIColor = UIColor(resource: .primary) {
        didSet {
            setupStatusLines()
        }
    }
    
    
    private let statusLineHeight: CGFloat = 2
    private let statusLinePadding: CGFloat = 10.0
    private let lineSpacing: CGFloat = 6.0
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupView()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupView()
    }
    
    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        setupView()
    }
    
    private func setupView() {
        backgroundColor = UIColor.white // Set background color
        
        // Add any additional setup for the view here
    }
    
    private func setupStatusLines() {
        // Remove any existing status lines
        subviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() }
        
        let numberOfLines = CGFloat(statusLines)
        let totalSpacing = lineSpacing * (numberOfLines - 1)
        let availableWidth = bounds.width - (2 * statusLinePadding) - totalSpacing
        let lineWidth = availableWidth / numberOfLines
        
        var currentX: CGFloat = statusLinePadding
        
        // Add status lines
        for index in 1...statusLines {
            let label = UILabel()
            label.text = ""
            label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16.0)
            label.numberOfLines = 1
            label.textAlignment = .center
            label.frame = CGRect(x: currentX, y: 0, width: lineWidth, height: statusLineHeight)
            label.layer.cornerRadius = statusLineHeight / 2
            label.clipsToBounds = true
            // Apply background colors
            
            if index < currentLineIndex {
                label.backgroundColor = previousColor // Green for previous line
            } else if index > currentLineIndex {
                label.backgroundColor =  nextColor// Grey for next line
            } else {
                label.backgroundColor = gradientColor() // Apply gradient color to the current line
            }
            
            addSubview(label)
            currentX += lineWidth + lineSpacing
        }
    }
    
    private func gradientColor() -> UIColor {
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = bounds
        gradientLayer.colors = [gradientStart.cgColor, gradientEnd.cgColor] // Customize your gradient colors here
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.4, y: 0)
  
        
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(gradientLayer.bounds.size, gradientLayer.isOpaque, 0.0)
        gradientLayer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return UIColor(patternImage: image!)
    }
}
```

You can set colours and other properties from storyboard [image: check here]
[image: here]